# Доступ к Spring-контексту из наследника javafx.application.Application

Tags: java, spring, javafx

В [этом примере](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Getting-a-Reference-to-the-ApplicationContext-in-a-Spring-Application?language=en_US) показано, как в получать доступ к контексту в общем случае.

```
package foo;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class MyBeanImpl implements ApplicationContextAware {
   private ApplicationContext ctx;

   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
     this.ctx=context;
   }
}
```

Не получилось воспроизвести это в моём приложении:

```java
package dev.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


@Component
public class GUI_Service extends javafx.application.Application implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  // ...


  public static void startGUI() {
    launch();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX test");

    // ...
  }

  private void initializeRootLayout() {

    FXMLLoader FXML_Loader = new FXMLLoader();
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println(this.applicationContext); // null !!!
    // дальше бессмысленно
  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }
}
```

В методе `initializeRootLayout` контекст всё ещё null.

Конфигурация:

```
package dev.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;


@Configuration
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

  @Bean
  public GUI_Service GUI_Service() { return new GUI_Service(); }
  // ...
}
```

[Репозиторий с приложением в нерабочем состоянии](https://bitbucket.org/TokugawaYD/javafx-spring-training/src/Error2/)

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки `@Bean` используют для специфичного создания, у вас же можно просто зарегистрировать их самому в `ApplicationContext` или указать их пакеты для сканирования.

По поводу `ApplicationContextAware`, почему бы вам просто не использовать `@Autowired` или `@Inject` для `private ApplicationContext applicationContext;`?

```
@Component
public class GUI_Service extends javafx.application.Application {
  @Inject
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! "у вас же можно просто зарегистрировать их самому" - естественный вопрос новичка в Spring: как это сделать? "почему бы вам просто не использовать @Autowired" - IntelliJ IDEA подсказывает, что это не рекомендовано. Нашел [статью](https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/) по этому поводу.

Comment: У `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` есть методы  которые помогут  в регистрации. Не рекомендуется инжектить через поля(но в некоторых ситуациях это нужно), можете сделать конструктор и повесить на него аннотацию.